# want to hide next button when it displays the last div

Tags: javascript, html, button, hide

can you guys help me. i want to hide button when last div is displayed? 
when next div is displayed then the button hides and show no more the 2 divs.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("#next").click(function()
    {
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
        {
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();

            if($('.divs').find('div').last())
            {
                 $("#next").hide();
             }
        }

        return false;
    });
}

html:


<div class="divs">
    <div class="cls1">1</div>
    <div class="cls2">2</div>
    <div class="cls3">3</div>
    <div class="cls4">4</div>
    <div class="cls5">5</div>
    <div class="cls6">6</div>
    <div class="cls7">7</div>
</div>
<a id="next">next</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your code here:

```
if($('.divs').find('div').last())
        {
             $("#next").hide();
         }
```

This returns `true` on the first click, resulting in hiding the button the first time you click it. What you need to do, is check if there are no elements after the visible div, and that's when you hide it. This should do the trick:

```
$("#next").click(function()
{
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
    {
        $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length == 0)
        {
            $("#next").hide();
        }
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: @user3193259 Glad I could help :) And welcome to StackOverflow! If you see an answer that helps you and you choose to use it, please accept it by choosing the "v" icon underneath the score.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#next").click(function()
{
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
    {
        $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    }
    else {
       $('#next').hide();
       return false;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: i tried but this also has a problem. when last div is displayed still there is a next button there and when i click on the button then it hides :/. any help?

Comment: This fails because you don't change the reference to the visible div when trying to hide. The "if" needs to be asked again, since you change the visible element.